# PowerBI - Want to embed the interactive visualization in Outlook

Tags: outlook, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am learning powerBi. I have created few visualizations and would want to share it to stakeholders over the outlook mail body as many of them has no access to the powerBi when send over link.

Is it possible to embed the interactive visualizations in the mail body just as we see in the workspace. It would be really great if someone can throwsome light.

As a matter of fact, I worked to find a add on which I thought will act as a tab when installed in the Oultook but that never worked.

Looking forward to some possible outcomes.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to embed Power BI content into an Outlook email body because embedding a report requires an iframe with some JavaScript code required to initialize the iframe and then embed the report.

For your scenario, it is suggested to embed a report/dashboard/visual in a web page using [Embed for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers) approach and share it with your stakeholders in an email. You can refer to various Power BI Embedded samples developed in different languages on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples).